# TSQL matching string in result set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a history table column that contains an `action` of events that take place within a request. The column data looks like this.

```
Updated Status | Open - New > Open - Assigned
```

I am trying to come up with a query where I can find all requests where a status is `Open - Assigned`.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE status = '%' + action + '%';
```

Since the action contains both the previous status (to the left of the Carrot) and the new status (to the right of the carrot) I am getting false matches.

Is there a way I can say search after `>` which will allow mean to find all requests that have been moved into that current status?

Comment: I find it a bit hard to understand the question. Could you please clarify it by sharing some sample data and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: It seems like the biggest issue you are facing here is normalization. If your data was properly normalized you would not have any issue finding the rows that meet your criteria.

Comment: @SeanLange this was just an excel dump that I threw into a table so I could better manipulate it. Hate VBA macros :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(status),0,CHARINDEX('>',REVERSE(status)))) like '%' +  action + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE status LIKE '%' + @action
```

Will find actions that ends with @action parameter.

You can also seek for '>' then take substring at right then search but it will be too complicated

Comment: Correct, but if I was looking for the status of 'Open - New' it's going to give me all items that have previously been in that status  as well as any that are now in that status. I guess I am trying to treat the 'action' as two separate values. Left of carrot is 'previousStatus', right of carrot is 'NewStatus'. I am trying to find all data where 'NewStatus="Open - New"'

Comment: @SBB note that I removed last `%`. Does it helps?